# Font awesome icon not displaying inside ag-grid cell in Angular 8

Tags: angular, font-awesome, ag-grid

I'm trying to learn Angular so following guides on installing and using ag-grid and Font Awesome, but I can't get an fa-icon to display inside an ag-grid cell using the cellRenderer. If I use the same icon HTML outside of the grid, it displays correctly. And if I put something like a link in place of the icon in the cell, it displays correctly. Here is my code:

**component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core'

import { faUserEdit } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent {
  faUserEdit = faUserEdit;

  columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: '', field: 'id',
      cellRenderer: (params) =>
        '<fa-icon [icon]="faUserEdit"></fa-icon>'
    },
    { headerName: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName'},
    { headerName: 'First Name', field: 'firstName'}
  ]
...
```

**component.html**

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-material"
             [rowData]="users"
             [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Without looking into exactly why (may be due to how they render their grid), I do see that ag has it's own icons and methods of changing/overriding those icons. If all else fails, you could look into that https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-icons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remember**, when you use inline `cellRenderer` - **you can implement just  `HTML` template** (no logic), for logic handling you need to create custom `cellRenderer` which will contain needed functions and so on.

> you wouldn't be able to execute `component` functions through `cellRenderer` inline implementation

But back to your issue here is a solution:

```
cellRenderer: (params) => { return '<i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>'; }
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/e9o67R?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well but it didn't work either - still shows up blank. I followed this tutorial to install font awesome in my project: https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Not sure if that works a different way or not.

Comment: For the fortawesome library, make sure you add every icon you are using to the icon library, or add a whole icon pack. Otherwise, it won't include it in the build. See here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/icon-library.md

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer since your demo worked. I didn't figure it out, but found Material Design for Bootstrap and am having more luck with it.

Comment: @TyCox94 still unable to get it? try to create a new question and share your code as much as you can and I will try to help

Comment: @un.spike my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505741/ag-grid-cellrenderer-with-font-awesome-icons