# Ag-grid cellRenderer with Font Awesome Icons

Tags: angular, font-awesome, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am attempting to add [Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) Icons via cellRenderer in ag-grid.

How can I properly render `<fa-icon>` tags within a cell render?

Here is what I attempted:

```js
    {
      width: 150,
      headerName: 'Events',
      // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
      cellRenderer: (params: any) => {
        const PHD: boolean = params.data.PHD;
        const DG: boolean = params.data.DG;
        const HOT: boolean = params.data.HOT;
        let result = '';
        if (PHD) {
          result = result + '<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>';
        }
        if (DG) {
          result = result + '';
        }
        if (HOT) {
          result = result + '';
        }
        return result;
      },
      resizable: true,
      filter: false,
    },
```

Here is how it renders from cellRenderer:
[image]

Placing the  tag within the component HTML works and renders to the page like this:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fa-icon` is a custom angular component which won't be parsed by your simple cell renderer.

Instead of this

```
'<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>'
```

you should use the simpler `<i>` approach

```
'<span><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i></span>';
```

for your simple cell renderer to work.

However if you want still want to use the fa-icon angular component, then you should look into implementing a cell Renderer component as described [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#angular-cell-render-components).

Comment: Wanna add some more, if you use inline `cellRenderer` you **can't** use any other components or directives even if they are inbuilt and **no logic** related to grid or interface also.

[check here also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52756127/4483102)

Comment: <i> example did not work, BUT the cell renderer component example did! Thank you guys.