# Edit icon not displaying in ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ag-grid

version:

- Angular: 10.0.10
- @angular/cli                      10.0.6

I install the bootstrap using below command

- npm install @coreui/angular --save
- npm install bootstrap

see code:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      })
```

registraion.component.cs

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { BackendserviceService } from '../backendservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})

export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

   columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'empid', field: 'empid' },
    { headerName: 'username', field: 'username' },
    { headerName: 'empaddress', field: 'empaddress' },
    { headerName: 'password', field: 'password' },
    { headerName: 'country', field: 'country' },
    {
      headerName: 'Edit',
      template:
        '<span><i class="fa fa-edit" data-action-type="edit"></i></span>',
    }
  ];
```

when i click on edit icon inspect

[image]

[image: edit icon not appearing]

Comment: see this not work after add the @NearHuscarl suggesttion  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbm22.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```js
template: '<span><i class="fa fa-edit" data-action-type="edit"></i></span>',
```

with

```js
cellRenderer: () => '<span><i class="fa fa-edit" data-action-type="edit"></i></span>',
```

See [cell renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#cell-rendering) section for more info

There are many ways to setup font-awesome, but if you want to setup quickly, just add the font-awesome css file to your index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css"
    />
  </head>
</html>
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit AgGrid Font-Awesome]

Comment: I replace as you said but not appearing the icon help please

Comment: did you install font-awesome package?

Comment: You can follow the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome)

Comment: after installing this command ```npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons``` not displaying edit icon

Comment: this line perfect works ```template: '<span><i class="fa fa-edit" data-action-type="edit"></i></span>',``` and I forget this line to add in inde.html ```<link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" />``` thanks for help

Comment: I didn't know that. but you can also pass params in the callback for further transformations if you use `cellRenderer`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ag-grid Cell Renderer.

`cellRenderer: (params) => {return '<span><i class="fa fa-edit" data-action-type="edit"></i></span>'}`

For more details read - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Comment: Not work Is this necessary to install font-awesome package? because I did not install font awsome package

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60528581/font-awesome-icon-not-displaying-inside-ag-grid-cell-in-angular-8